# OpenLayers Maker opacity independent to Icon

Tags: icons, opacity, openlayers, marker

In OpenLayers can I make a Marker's opacity to be independent to its Icon's opacity ?

Comment: what do you mean by independent? marker IS an icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using [styling](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html) and the `graphicOpacity` attribute.